# Export array for jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: scala.js

I want to export an array of names to be accessible by jQuery UI for autocompletion.

I defined an array:

```
  @(JSExport @field)
  val possibleNames = Array("AB", "CD", "ED")
```

and tried to use it in JavaScript:

```
$("#NameInput").autocomplete(
    { source: example.NameTest().possibleNames }
);
```

However this give me an error:

> TypeError: this.source is not a function
>
> this.source( { term: value }, this._response() );

I tried to export a function like

```
  @JSExport 
 def testFunction(): Array[String] = {
       Array("AB", "CD", "ED") 
  }
```

But the result is the same.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because an `Array` is not a JavaScript array that jQuery can understand. You need to export a `js.Array` instead.